# Do you memorize the tags in your XML configuration?

Tags: java, xml, configuration

1. Do you guys memorize the tags in
   your XML configurations particularly
   in Java?
2. Do you guys memorize the tags in
   web.xml, in your Ant configuration
   files, in your Spring configuration
   files?
3. Also do you code them by hand or do
   you have an IDE and a reference with
   you?

I'm a noob wanting to know how the pros do it :)

Comment: Should probably be community wiki since this is more of a poll than an actual question with a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to remember the most common cases, and look up the remainder via manuals...

I tend not to use IDEs which remember stuff for me, and much prefer to use vim or other fancy text editors for development. This approach isn't for everyone, but after many years of programming in a dozen different languages/tools, (up to half a dozen simulaneously sometimes!) I find it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd go get an editor w/ schema support and rely on intellisense.  I guess I'm just being lazy :).  On the other hand, why would I want to remember all those angle brackets on top of my head, hehehe.  Make your already hard life easier I say.  Work smart, not harder.  If tool can do this for you, use it.  If not, well... no choice right?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. I pretty much just hit ctrl-space in Eclipse. :)

The exception being Spring, where I have something like 5 tags to remember - `beans`, `bean` `property`, ...

Comment: so you don't use any of the spring namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Most important/used tags will be memorized by daily usage. Meanwhile I rely in my favourite Ide's autocompletion or product documentation to acomplish this. My memory has limited space :-)

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't remember them all, it is important to know them and what they exactly do. I think you have to understand a XML configuration file without the help of an IDE.

Working with a XML skeleton which is passed from project to project, without understanding it all, can be dangerous when you got problem.